# other method to implement varargs

Tags: c++, swig

i have to write a method, that takes in parameters 1, 2, 3 ....or 32 integers.
we call call this mthod f like that
f(1)
f(1,5)
f(1,2,6,16,32)
...
i have then to export the method  with swig, to be used after that in another langage.
the best manner to do i had found, is to use varargs
f(number,...)
but i think swig doesn't support such functions to export.

the other way is to use surcharge
f(int)
f(int,int)
f(int,int,int)
....
and write that 32 times

is there a better way to do it? (with templates of #define preprocessor macros)

thx

Comment: I do not know swig, but by far the easiest way to have variable number of parameters of the same type is to use a vector.

Comment: don't know swig either, but have you read [this](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Varargs.html) ?

Comment: i changed the solution.
with swig when we do %template
it wraps all the template body, i have done this for vector, and the vectors are now exported. After that i changed the varargs with a vector.
>Thx